# Show layered navigation even when Anchor = NO (magento 1)

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

does anybody know a way to show the layered navigation even when set anchor = NO
Tried to find a solution trough google but it looks like no solution is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are layout difference between them (in catalog.xml)

**For Non-Anchor**

```
 <catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
```

**For Anchor**

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
```

For the **Non-anchor** is calling below block

```
<reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

**For Anchor**

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

Just Replace the block in left it will work.

Comment: This is so cool, a small direction to the correct place and I got it working. Thanks a lot men. I replaced catelog_category_default with the layered one and then updated my aw_layerednavigation to include the default one and done :-)